# Permissions on directories when extracting tar built from a list of files

Tags: linux, permissions, tar

I'm creating a tar file from a list of files with the -T option.  When extracting the tar file, subdirectory permissions are root:root instead of the permissions on the directory itself?  Any ideas how to fix this?

Example:

## # cat filelist.txt

> file1.txt
>
> dir1/file2.txt
>
> dir1/dir2/file3.txt

## # tar cf files.tar -T filelist.txt

## # tar xf files.tar

Ownership on extracted files match original ownership on file1.txt, file2.txt, and file3.txt
Ownership on dir1 and dir2 does not match.  Owner is root:root

I could follow a solution similar to [Preserve ownership & rights of parent directory when extracting tar archive](https://superuser.com/questions/1175794/preserve-ownership-rights-of-parent-directory-when-extracting-tar-archive)
but was hoping there was another way as that might add up to some more work for a bunch of directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to back up the directories as well as the files, for which you have to do two things:-

1) Add the directories to your file list:

```
file1.txt
dir1
dir1/file2.txt
dir1/dir2
dir1/dir2/file3.txt
```

2) Add `--no-recursion` to the back-up run string to stop all the other files in the directories being included:

```
tar cf files.tar --no-recursion -T filelist.txt
```

Note that the order is important: the directories must precede any reference in a subdirectory or file; and the `--no-recursion` parameter must come before the `-T`, but after the `cf FileName` command.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that.  I found some awk magic in this post that will add the directories to my file list.

https://serverfault.com/questions/877254/tar-does-not-retain-directory-permissions/